# The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'aws-context:context-credentials

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, spring-cloud

I have been trying to set up and test Amazon's SQS locally using the Spring cloud with AWS using the steps mentioned at [cloud.spring.io](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-aws/spring-cloud-aws.html#_messaging)

I have used maven to include the following dependencies

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <spring-cloud-aws-version>1.0.0.RELEASE</spring-cloud-aws-version>
    <java.version>1.7</java.version>
</properties>    
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-aws-autoconfigure</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-cloud-aws-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-aws-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-cloud-aws-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-aws-messaging</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-cloud-aws-version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

The dependencies were imported successfully. In my Spring config, I tried to set the aws context and the queueMessagingTemplate

```
<beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:aws-messaging="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cloud/aws/messaging"
   xmlns:aws-context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cloud/aws/context"
   xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/cloud/aws/messaging http://www.springframework.org/schema/cloud/aws/messaging/spring-cloud-aws-messaging-1.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/cloud/aws/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/cloud/aws/context/spring-cloud-aws-context-1.0.xsd">

<aws-context:context-credentials>
    <aws-context:instance-profile-credentials />
</aws-context:context-credentials>

<aws-messaging:queue-messaging-template id="queueMessagingTemplate" />
```

The problem is in my spring context i am getting the error

```
cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'aws-
 context:context-credentials'.
- schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://www.springframework.org/schema/cloud/aws/
 context/spring-cloud-aws-context-1.0.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be 
 read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
```

The **spring-cloud-aws-context-1.0.xsd** is in the classpath in the **spring-cloud-aws-context-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar** but still the error is there. Not able to figure out why this is happening. If someone can tell me how to fix it, would be very helpful.

Thanks,
Tatha

Comment: http://www.springframework.org/schema/cloud/aws/
 context/spring-cloud-aws-context-1.0.xsd doesn't have anything for me.  the URL its complaining about doesn't exist so its a legit error.

Comment: There is only one xsd under http://www.springframework.org/schema/cloud/ and that is spring-cloud.xsd. Can you someone from the Spring cloud team point out where the xsds for spring-cloud-aws-context or spring-cloud-aws-messaging-1.0.xsd can be found. As per the documentation in the spring cloud teh url should be  http://www.springframework.org/schema/cloud/aws/
 context/spring-cloud-aws-context-1.0.xsd

Comment: It's not supposed to go to the actual URL via internet to find the xsd. spring-cloud-aws-context-VERSION.jar has a file `spring.schemas` in its `META-INF` folder, which intercepts the `http://www.springframework.org/schema/cloud/aws/context/spring-cloud-aws-context-1.0.xsd` to be an xsd file in the jar under `org/springframework/cloud/aws/context/config/xml/spring-cloud-aws-context-1.0.xsd` For some reason this isn't activating

Comment: see also: 
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/extensible-xml.html#extensible-xml-registration-spring-schemas